# How can I import Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-modules

I would like to get rid of global variables in my Jest test code. Specifically `describe`, `it`, and `expect`:

```js
describe('Welcome (Snapshot)', () => {
  it('Welcome renders hello world', () => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

So I tried to add:

```js
import { describe, it } from 'jest';
```

and

```js
import jest from 'jest';

jest.describe('Welcome (Snapshot)', () => {
  jest.it('Welcome renders hello world', () => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

And other variation but it's not working.

How can I get my Jest test code working without globals?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4473

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After I realized Jest is running in Node.js, it realized I could do this:

```
let { describe, it } = global;
```

It is not perfect, but one step closer... now I don't need to configure my linter with global variables any more.

Comment: What linter are you using? ESLint comes with a Jest environment.

Comment: @Scimonster standard.. BUT! I don't think I want to configure something such a jest environment for my linter, that would require me to define a linter task for each "environment"

Comment: This is also helpful if you use flow or any other static analysis tools on your test files

Answer (score 32):

The simplest solution for this is adding `jest: true` to your `env` configuration in [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint), like so:

```
"env": {
  "browser": true,
  "node": true,
  "jasmine": true,
  "jest": true,
  "es6": true
},
```

Comment: For reference, here are [all the ways to configure the ESLint environment](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) (for Jest or other situations)

Answer (score 31):

Try the code below:

```js
import {describe, expect, it} from '@jest/globals'
```

> if you prefer explicit imports, you can do import {describe, expect, test} from '@jest/globals'.

Source https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api

Comment: If I do that, method `toBeInTheDocument` is marked as missing.

Comment: @Danon, The following SO post suggests you're importing from the wrong location. "You need to install jest-dom to enable it." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547215/react-testing-library-why-is-tobeinthedocument-not-a-function#answer-56557915

Comment: Note that in order to import `jest` from `@jest/globals`, for now you need to disable injecting globals by passing `--injectGlobals=false` as an argument to the jest command. For more on this issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9920

Comment: this worked for me also to eliminate the "not found in assertion type" which appeared in intellij

Comment: "Do not import `@jest/globals` outside of the Jest test environment" Sadly this doesn't cure my storybook woes.

Answer (score 6):

I similarly don't like using or relying on global variables, and after copy/pasting various workarounds in different projects, I decided to create [`jest-without-globals`](https://github.com/agilgur5/jest-without-globals) as a *very* tiny wrapper to support importing Jest's features.

[Per the *usage* documentation](https://github.com/agilgur5/jest-without-globals#usage), it's straightforward to use:

> ```
> import { describe, it, expect } from 'jest-without-globals'
>
> describe('describe should create a section', () => {
>   it('it should checkmark', () => {
>     expect('').toBe('')
>    })
> })
> ```
>
> All of the functions available in [Jest's API](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api), as well as `jest` and `expect`, can be imported from `jest-without-globals`.

Using `jest-without-globals`, I don't need to copy/paste workarounds anymore and don't need to configure settings like ESLint's `jest` environment, it just works as a simple import.

It's also written in TypeScript, so you have typings out-of-the-box and it's fully tested to ensure it keeps working correctly.

Comment: You can now explicitly import all of these directly from Jest. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324636/how-can-i-import-jest/64396131#64396131) for details.