# VS Code not recognizing Jest, underlining with Intellisense

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I'm using VS Code in a Typescript project that uses Jest for testing.  For some reason, VS Code thinks that the Jest globals are not available:

[image: VS Code intellisense underlining Jest in red]

I have the Jest typedefs installed in my dev dependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
    // ...truncated
    "@types/jest": "^20",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "ts-jest": "^20.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.0"
}
```

Comment: I have tried to make `npm i @types/jest` and VSCode discovered `jest` global object. Try to reinstall/restart/clear cache...

Comment: Can you share your `.tsconfig`?

Comment: It may be a silly question, but did you import the objects you're using? Also, this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324636/how-to-import-jest

Comment: Jest is setup as a global object so as to not need to import those functions in every test file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my version of Typescript to 2.8 and this problem went away.  I'm going to assume it was some sort of cache issue.

Comment: I have seen that using the "Restart TS Server" command from Cmd+Shift+P can help sometimes.   Ensuring my tsconfig file was being loaded and had the correct settings was also important, as was this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874114/intellisense-for-jest-not-working-in-vs-code

Answer (score 11):

Correct answer here is that typescript requires type declarations for jest before jest global objects are visible for intellisense.

Add this triple-slash directive to beginning of your test file:

```
/// <reference types="jest" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I've similarly struggled with this problem a number of times despite having `@types/jest` in my `devDependencies` too.

I created [`jest-without-globals`](https://github.com/agilgur5/jest-without-globals) as a *very* tiny wrapper to support importing Jest's features instead of relying on globals, thereby ensuring the variables exist.

It's written in TypeScript as well, ensuring that it's typed properly when imported and that you don't need to do anything other than an import to make the types function.

[Per the Usage docs](https://github.com/agilgur5/jest-without-globals#usage), it's straightforward to use:

> ```
> import { describe, it, expect } from 'jest-without-globals'
>
> describe('describe should create a section', () => {
>   it('it should checkmark', () => {
>     expect('').toBe('')
>    })
> })
> ```
>
> All of the functions available in [Jest's API](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api), as well as `jest` and `expect`, can be imported from `jest-without-globals`.