# Intellisense for Jest not working in VS code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jestjs, intellisense

### Edit:   Run `npm install @types/jest --save-dev` To fix

Just trying to type `it()` and the auto suggestion is `isTag`

[image]

I've tried adding a jsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6"
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "assets"
  ]
}
```

Thank you for anyone who has a suggestion for this!!

Comment: https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/440, https://tekloon.dev/autocomplete-for-jest-in-vscode "npm i -D @types/jest"

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Add to your `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "jest"
        ]
    }
}
```

If this do not work try with this command:

```
npm install @types/jest
```

or

```
yarn add -D @types/jest
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still getting the same results.

Comment: Do you have `jest` npm package installed?

Comment: Updated my answer, give it a try please.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!!  would you recommend globally installing this?

Comment: Nice! As you wish, you can install globally or have it installed as a dev dependency.

Comment: @types/jest shows `jest not found` when run `npm run start`

Comment: You first have to install jest locally or globally: `npm i jest`. Assuming you have a project of two directories like `backend` and `frontend` put this file in them both. Then restart vscode. Autocomplete should be working now.

Comment: This was the magic `npm install @types/jest`

Comment: Installing `@types/jest` worked.

Comment: I CONFIRM that we need to restart VSCODE after install @types/jest and it works!

Comment: Please clarify where can I find "jsconfig.json", I have package.json file only

Answer (score 68):

***Update 2024***

Just install `@types/jest` via this command:

```
npm i @types/jest --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add -D @types/jest
```

Comment: i would update this to say 'npm i @types/jest --save-dev' this should not be exported with the project as a normal dependency and is only for local testing

Comment: this worked. dont rob npm like that, we have -D option too instead of verbose --save-dev haha

Comment: Yes, but `--save-dev` is more meaningful and suitable for tutorial aspects.

Comment: I added a small edit to the top of this question in the context of SOLUTION:

Answer (score 22):

```
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "jest"
        ]
    }
}
```

for those who have no luck adding above to `jsconfig.json` in the root folder: try adding it to tests folder (the folder containing `*.test.js` files)

Comment: Thank you. Put this inside test folder (not the root one) is working for me.

Comment: why the same thing works for some, and not for others?

Comment: So far, none of these answers works for me. Installed types and tried this config folder in both the root and the tests folder. Zero progress.

Comment: This worked, I think it's because I am changing `roots` in my `jest.config.js`, so I had to put`jsconfig.json` inside my root folder.

Answer (score 5):

This won't be for everyone but if the codebase has multiple packages in a monorepo and you use vscode as your editor, you might want to install `@types/jest` in the root, rather in the individually packages.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had the intuition but did not try, saw this and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The Typescript extension was the root cause of my issue. I was trying to use Jest, but the `expect` type was being overridden by the `expect` from `expect.js`, which was apparently being auto-installed into a global cache by Typescript at `/Users/cameronhudson/Library/Caches/typescript/5.0/node_modules/@types/expect.js`. My preliminary "fix" is to disable automatic type acquisition by the Typescript extension. This can be done in the settings for the extension.

[image]

I have a feeling that this is a heavy-handed solution, but hopefully it will lead someone to a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm i -D @types/jest
```

it adds a line automaticaly in package.json :

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
        "jest": "^29.5.0"
      }
```

You have nothing else to do.

Comment: You are a life saver

Comment: You are my life saver!

Answer (score 1):

Non of the solution works for me. After diving into some github repos in which I found it working, I found a file called `jest.config.js`. Following are the configs of the file:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testRegex: './src/.*\\.(test|spec)?\\.(ts|ts)$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
};
```

**Note:** This is for `ts`. Change all the `ts` with `js` if you are not using typescript.
After saving, Restart Vscode and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Where you call it makes a difference. Sometimes intellisense doesn't work when you are in a bad function or code block.

So if you try:

```
  beforeEach(() => ({
    mockedUseAccount.
  }));
```

Intellisense doesn't work.

If you try:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockedUseAccount.
  });
```

Intellisense works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that these haven't been shared - Use jsdoc instead:

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

jest.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  verbose: true,
};

module.exports = config;
```

```js
/** @returns {Promise<import('jest').Config>} */
module.exports = async () => {
  return {
    verbose: true,
  };
};
```

If you're using a TypeScript file (jest.config.ts):

```
import type {Config} from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
  verbose: true,
};

export default config;
```

```
import type {Config} from 'jest';

export default async (): Promise<Config> => {
  return {
    verbose: true,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is indeed to install `@types/jest`:

```
yarn add -D @types/jest
```

However, if you have that installed and Jest's functions (`describe`, `it`, etc.) still have no type information in VS Code, check your your `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json`.

I had made some custom types for a package that didn't have any and placed them in a `./types` folder. To get TypeScript to recognise those, I added `typeRoots: ["./types"]` to my `tsconfig.json`. However, [specifying type roots there overrides TypeScript's default value of `["./node_modules/@types"]`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots), thus it will no longer be able to find `@types/jest`.

So, if you have a custom value for `typeRoots` in your `tsconfig.json`, then besides installing `@types/jest`, make sure you also include this (replace `./types` with any other custom type root folders you have configured):

```json
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"],
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing has been worked so far, you can try this.

check `"types": ["node","jest"],` in tsconfig.json file.

If jest is not added in the list, add and restart VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this mentioned before but using explicit imports are a valid option if the dependencies are already in the package.json and vscode is still not getting the message. In my case vscode kept intellisensing mocha for describe, it, beforeAll, and expect.

I tried all options but creating a jsconfig.json

S/o @vikramvi for [his comment](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/440) on OP's question which led me to that solution.

Before explicit imports
[image: Before explicit imports 1]
[image: Before explicit imports 2]

After explicit imports
[image: After explicit imports]

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `tsc --init` to generate a `tsconfig.json` file. After that, VSCode picked up the types.