# How to use Jest intellisense with create-react-app and VScode?

Tags: create-react-app

From [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2564), I figured out that Jest is installed underneath the hood, but because of that, I can't install it manually, and because of that I don't see Jest IntelliSense in my files [even when I add jsconfig.json in my vscode folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874114/intellisense-for-jest-not-working-in-vs-code). How can I make IntelliSense visible?