# react-testing-library why is toBeInTheDocument() not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Here is my code for a tooltip that toggles the CSS property `display: block` on MouseOver and on Mouse Out `display: none`.

```
 it('should show and hide the message using onMouseOver and onMouseOut events respectively', () => {
    const { queryByTestId, queryByText } = render(
      <Tooltip id="test" message="test" />,
    )
    fireEvent.mouseOver(queryByTestId('tooltip'))
    expect(queryByText('test')).toBeInTheDocument()
    fireEvent.mouseOut(queryByTestId('tooltip'))
    expect(queryByText('test')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
    cleanup()
  })
```

I keep getting the error  TypeError: expect(...).toBeInTheDocument is not a function

Has anyone got any ideas why this is happening? My other tests to render and snapshot the component all work as expected. As do the queryByText and queryByTestId.

Comment: I've posted a detailed answer for those who struggle using `ts-jest` without `babel-jest` and nothing works. I hope it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66708479/2170368

Answer (score 425, accepted):

`toBeInTheDocument` is not part of RTL. You need to install [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/) to enable it.

And then import it in your test files by:

```tsx
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
```

Comment: how do you import it, you could have provided the full answer here...

Comment: @EugenSunic Simply use `import '@testing-library/jest-dom'`

Comment: @Cog , is it always like that?

Comment: In Create React App `import '@testing-library/jest-dom'` will be in setupTests.ts. When upgrading from an older Create React App you need to create setupTests.ts. See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template-typescript/template/src/setupTests.ts

Comment: To clarify, it is not only in jest-dom. Other supporting libraries such as Jasmine support it too.

Comment: If you have `tsconfig.json` you can try to add next: `"types": ["@testing-library/jest-dom"]`,

Answer (score 161):

As mentioned by Giorgio, you need to install jest-dom.  Here is what worked for me:

(I was using typescript)

```sh
npm i --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom
```

Then add an import to your setupTests.ts

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
```

Then in your [jest.config.js](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration) you can load it via:

```js
"setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
```

Comment: ESLint complains about jest.config.js syntax?

Comment: I think you need to nest it inside `module.exports = { ... }`

Comment: Jest was working fine with the above solution, but VSCode was still complaining (_Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type..._), so I had to install the types as well : ```yarn add @types/testing-library__jest-dom --dev```

Comment: Fab313 comment works for me.

Answer (score 15):

When you do `npm i @testing-library/react` make sure there is a setupTests.js file with the following statement in it

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
```

Comment: Are you sure?  What happens at `npm i` that helps?

Answer (score 11):

Some of the accepted answers were basically right but some may be slightly outdated:
Some references that are good for now:

- https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
- https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

Here are the full things you need:

1. in the project's `<rootDir>` (aka where `package.json` and `jest.config.js` are), make sure you have a file called `jest.config.js` so that Jest can automatically pick it up for configuration. The file is in JS but is structured similarly to a package.json.
2. Make sure you input the following:

```js
  module.exports = {
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules', '<rootDir>/dist'], // might want?
    moduleNameMapper: {
      '@components(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/components$1' // might want?
    },
    moduleDirectories: ['<rootDir>/node_modules', '<rootDir>/src'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/jest-setup.ts'] // this is the KEY
    // note it should be in the top level of the exported object.
  };
```

3. Also, note that if you're using typescript you will need to make sure your `jest-setup.ts` file is compiled (so add it to `src` or to the list of items to compile in your `tsconfig.json`.
4. At the top of `jest-setup.ts/js` (or whatever you want to name this entrypoint) file: add `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';`.
5. You may also want to make sure it actually runs so put a `console.log('hello, world!');`. You also have the opportunity to add any global functions you'd like to have available in jest such as (`global.fetch = jest.fn()`).
6. Now you actually have to install `@testing-library/jest-dom`: `npm i -D @testing-library/jest-dom` in the console.

With those steps you should be ready to use jest-dom:

Without TS: you still need:

1. `npm i -D @testing-library/jest-dom`
2. Creating a `jest.config.js` and adding to it a minimum of: `module.exports = { setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/[path-to-file]/jest-setup.js'] }`.
3. Creating a `[path-to-file]/jest-setup.js` and adding to it: `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';`.

The jest-setup file is also a great place to configure tests like creating a special `renderWithProvider(` function or setting up global window functions.

Comment: adding it beneath /src/ when using typescript is a very important hint. I moved my setupTests.ts file due to some refactorings, which broke all tests then

Comment: This worked well, was the best explained answer with clear instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Having tried all of the advice in this post and it still not working for me, I'd like to offer an alternative solution:

Install jest-dom:

```
npm i --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom
```

Then create a `setupTests.js` file in the **src directory** (this bit is important! I had it in the root dir and this did *not* work...). In here, put:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
```

(or `require(...)` if that's your preference).

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 9):

None of the answers worked for me because I made the silly mistake of typing `toBeInDocument()` instead of `toBeInTheDocument()`. Maybe someone else did the same mistake :)

Answer (score 6):

I had a hard time solving that problem so I believe it's important to note the followings if you're using CREATE REACT APP for your project:

1. You DO NOT need a `jest.config.js` file to solve this, so if you have that you can delete it.
2. You DO NOT need to change anything in `package.json`.
3. You HAVE TO name your jest setup file `setupTests.js` and have it under the `src` folder. It WILL NOT work if your setup file is called `jest.setup.js` or `jest-setup.js`.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! There must be a way to change setupTests.js because probably some configuration key just defaults to this value.

Comment: Thanks, after 1h of trying..this was it! 
|setupTests.js seems to be not configurable in CRA. It is also one of the files generated by default (but probably everybody is deleting it from the start).
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/

Answer (score 5):

1. install required packages

   `npm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom eslint-plugin-jest-dom`
2. create `jest-setup.js` in the root folder of your project and add

   ```
   import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
   ```
3. in `jest.config.js`

   ```
   setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest-setup.js']
   ```
4. `TypeScript` only, add the following to the `tsconfig.json` file. Also, **change .js extension to .ts**.

   ```
   "include": ["./jest-setup.ts"]
   ```

`toBeInTheDocument()` and many similar functions are not part of the `React-testing-library`. It requires installing an additional package.

Comment: Thanks! But why would anyone want to use typescript?

Comment: Mr. Pudeyev, with respect, I believe that `JavaScript` is designed to perform how it is currently functioning, and TypeScript is developed to avoid quirky edges of JavaScript. We don't know JavaScript; we pretend we know---Getify. You should have deep knowledge of JavaScript to prevent them, so I personally use `TypeScript` to walk on the safety zone.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone out there that like is trying to run tests in Typescript with jest and is still getting the same error even after installing `@testing-library/jest-dom` and following all the other answers: you probably need to install the type definitions for `jest-dom` ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/testing-library__jest-dom)) with:

`npm i @types/testing-library__jest-dom`

or

`yarn add @types/testing-library__jest-dom`

You need to install them as real dependencies and not as `devDependency`.

Answer (score 3):

the problem already was solved, but i will comment a little tip here, you don't need to create a single file called setup just for this, you just need to specify the module of the jest-dom on the `setupFilesAfterEnv` option in your jest configuration file.

Like this:

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'],
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue but for `@testing-library/jasmine-dom` rather than `@testing-library/jest-dom`.

The process of setup is just a tiny bit different with jasmine. You need to set up the environment in a `before` function in order for the matchers to be added. I think jest-dom will go ahead and add the matchers when you first `import` but Jasmine does not.

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import MyComponent from './myComponent';
import JasmineDOM from '@testing-library/jasmine-dom';

describe("My Suite", function () {

  beforeAll(() => {
    jasmine.getEnv().addMatchers(JasmineDOM);
  })


  it('render my stuff', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<MyComponent />);
    const ele = screen.getByText(/something/i);
    expect(ele).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **react-script** then follow the below steps

1. Install `@testing-library/jest-dom` library if not done already using
   `npm i @testing-library/jest-dom`.
2. Put `import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"` in setUpTest.js

If you are using **jest** then import the library in `jest.setup.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have to use `@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect`, just make sure you're on the latest version and it should already be imported as part of `@testing-library/jest-dom` when using the `jest.setup.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TS
You could also add a test.d.ts file to your test directory and use a triple slash directive:
`///<reference types='@testing-library/jest-dom'>`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `"./jest.setup.js"` in the `"include"` array in `tsconfig.json`:

> "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx",
> ".next/types/**/*.ts", "./jest.setup.js"],

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the answers mentioned in the comments above in my case replacing '*import*' with '*require*' helped. Even though all other inner files are imported via '*import*' and other settings from the comments above were implemented too, they didn't helped until I've changed import

```
const { expect, describe, it } = require('@jest/globals');
```

Answer (score -5):

Instead of doing:

```
    expect(queryByText('test')).toBeInTheDocument()
```

you can find and test that it is in the document with just one line by using

```
    let element = getByText('test');
```

The test will fail if the element isn't found with the getBy call.