# Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'Matchers<any>'

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to write tests for my simple React App that creates a UI for a dog Shelter using API etc. I have imported the modules shown below and ran the following command

```
npm install jest-dom react-testing-library --save-dev
```

However, I'm getting the toBeInTheDocument(); method underlined in red and the error message

```
"Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'Matchers<any>'."
```

```
import "react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each";
import "jest-dom/extend-expect";

import * as React from "react";
import PetCard from "./PetCard";
import Pet from "./Pet";
import { render } from "react-testing-library";

const petMock = {
  id: "225c5957d7f450baec75a67ede427e9",
  name: "Fido",
  status: "available",
  kind: "dog",
  breed: "Labrador",
} as Pet;

describe("PetCard", () => {
  it("should render the name", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<PetCard pet={petMock} />);
    expect(getByText("Fido")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

});
```

Any advice on how I can resolve this is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like it might be eslint complaining, have you tried changing the eslint environment? Try dropping this at the top of your test file `/* eslint-env jest */`

Comment: thank you this worked :)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Please make sure that the correct types are installed in your project. i.e.

`npm i -D @testing-library/jest-dom@^4.2.4`

From my experience the Typescript types seem to be missing from version 5.x

Comment: You may also need to install the types:
`@types/testing-library__jest-dom`

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/123) explains why they removed type definitions from the core.

Comment: I am using react native, is this also for me?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa yes, if you are using Jest for your React Native application testing

Comment: I think "npm i -D @testing-library/jest-dom" would be better, it solved my problems :-)

Comment: Same as @Michiel - no need to specify specifically version 4.2.4 anymore

Comment: If you are still facing this issue after adding `@testing-library/jest-dom`. Ensure that in your test files you have imported `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';`. It is mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/123#issuecomment-689689656)

Comment: `npm i -D @types/testing-library__jest-dom` It worked with v^5.16.4!

Comment: I tried everything here, but I had another issue on top: I had an `import { describe, expect, test } from '@jest/globals';` statement after the `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';` which was giving me the wrong expect function. Make sure you don't have this extra import statement.

Answer (score 230):

Most of the answers here seem to address primarily Babel. If you don't use Babel it's enough to add `@testing-library/jest-dom` to your types.

So a few quick steps:

Make sure you've got the library installed:

```
yarn add -D @testing-library/jest-dom
```

or

```
npm i @testing-library/jest-dom --save-dev
```

and then link it in your *tsconfig.json*:

```
"types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
```

Now we tackle Jest configuration. Rather than import it in every test file it is better to do it in the Jest config file (usually it's called *jest.config.js*):

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: [
   "<rootDir>/support/setupTests.js"
],
```

and then in the file `setupTests.js`:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
```

or use to `require()` if using pure JavaScript or different configuration.

The alternative (for TypeScript or if you don't like adding *setupTests.js*) is to add `globals.d.ts` (in my case to the project root directory) and add there the line above (`import ...`).

**Note**: Both solution work **without** setting `esModuleInterop`.

**Note**: If using TypeScript, add the typings with `npm install @types/testing-library__jest-dom -D`

Comment: Was facing a problem with toBeVisible() not being found (TS2339: Property 'toBeVisible' does not exist on type 'JestMatchersShape<Matchers<void, any>, Matchers<Promise<void>, any>>'). Importing jest-dom/extend-expect solved it.

Comment: Shouldn't the `"types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"]` be in the ts-configs?

Comment: this isn't viable solely on `ts-jest` without `babel-jest` which requires an additional setup. Doing that you will get: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: @JjagweDennis yeah, reworded

Comment: Where does `setupFilesAfterEnv: [
   "<rootDir>/support/setupTests.js"
],`
 go?

Comment: @JamieHutber - top level as in the documentation https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array.

Comment: This got almost everything working for me. Had to remove and readd the jest-dom types and restart VS Code then everything worked!

i.e. I did a `yarn remove @testing-library/jest-dom` and a `yarn add @testing-library/jest-dom@XXX` where XXX was the version in my package.json I just removed. Looks like that also added `"@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5"` to my devDependencies which was likely the fix

Comment: For types, you have to add the type definitions: `yarn add -D @types/testing-library__jest-dom`

Comment: adding the "@testing-library/jest-dom" to the types array solved it for me. thanks

Comment: Was also facing a problem with `toBeVisible()` not being found. Turns out I was importing `expect` from `@jest/globals` instead of from `@testing-library/jest-dom`

Comment: This works to run the tests without importing @testing-library/jest-dom in each test, but how do I make IntelliJ not complain that it can't resolve the reference?

Comment: warning: create-react-app is deprecated - in case you see this error while trying to set up a new project with create-react-app, which just happened to me after doing that and deleting my package-lock.json file.

Comment: Webstorm was telling me `toBeInTheDocument` etc. weren't real functions with a NextJS app. The _only_ thing that fixed it was adding the types array to my tsconfig.json within the `compilerOptions` object. Importing `"@testing-library/jest-dom"` in the setup file makes the tests run, but the tsconfig change was needed for Webstorm to recognize and suggest RTL matchers.

Comment: Apparently, we need the types array because typescript automatically looks for types in `node_modules/@types`, but the types we're looking for here are not in an @types folder. The downside of using the `types` array is that typescript will only look at the packages specified, and nothing else. If you add the `types` array to your tsconfig and the IDE complains about other functions, you may have to specify more packages.

Comment: Sorry to spam comments. Here's a link to the documentation on the `types` array: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types

Comment: I think in recent version, you just need
```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0"
```
+
`import '@testing-library/jest-dom';` in your test file.

more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367514/vite-jest-react-testing

Comment: In to agree with comments from lortimer and Nor.Z: using the `"types"` config item seems like it could become laborious as you continually would need to add types; simply including `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';` at the top of the test file seems a much cleaner option.

Comment: @AlexanderNied depending how many test files you've got; for couple of hundred that's not ideal imho; complex test files contain a lot of imports which I personally find overwhelming. I prefer to limit repetitions in the same way as we no longer import React in every file (e.g. in Next13).

Comment: I had to import `'@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect'` for my tests to find the `toBeVisible()` function in react native.

Answer (score 31):

For `pnpm` users (who might be wondering why this works out of the box with npm), it's because pnpm uses a semi-strict node_modules layout, which means only a few packages are hoisted to the top (ie. accessible via a simple import/require)

See the docs here: https://pnpm.io/blog/2020/10/17/node-modules-configuration-options-with-pnpm#the-default-setup

That's why if you are using pnpm the quick-fix that's needed currently is

```
pnpm add -D @types/testing-library__jest-dom
```

To make it a bit more robust one could edit .npmrc and hoist only the dependency which is missing. [hoisting setting](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#dependency-hoisting-settings).

e.g.

```
public-hoist-pattern[]=@types*
public-hoist-pattern[]=@vitest/expect # if using vitest
public-hoist-pattern[]=@jest/expect # if using jest
public-hoist-pattern[]=@testing-library/jest-dom

# The settings in .npmrc seem to override the default settings
public-hoist-pattern[]=*eslint*
public-hoist-pattern[]=*prettier*
```

Comment: Even by installing `@types/testing-library__jest-dom` as a dev dependency or by adding the above configuration, with pnpm I still get the error, while with npm I have no issue.

Answer (score 23):

eslint overrides didn't help, but adding

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
```

in the beginning of the test file solved it.

I found this answer [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/36#issuecomment-527244995) and also in the jest setup [file](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/2de57fe15a69a84fadb08ce549599c7de5a9d3b2/packages/cra-template/template/src/setupTests.js) from the facebook's official [react starter app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html). I hope it helps.

Comment: This no longer exists with the latest version of '@testing-library/jest-dom'

Answer (score 15):

In my case it was enough to:

- add to the **package.json** in devDependencies and install:

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
```

- add to the **.spec** file:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

Comment: How about for react native ?

Comment: Adding the import in the `.spec` file was the key ingredient

Answer (score 9):

The recent versions of `@testing-library/jest-dom` (e.g. `5.11.2`) work out of the box, the issue for me was caused by cypress types conflicting with `@types/chai` used by `@testing-library`:

> Since Chai and jQuery are namespaces (globals), incompatible versions will cause the package manager (yarn or npm) to nest and include multiple definitions and cause conflicts.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html#Configure-tsconfig-json

Solved by not including the `cypress` folder in the top-level TS config but instead adding `cypress/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The selected answer is usually correct if you are using `babel-jest` for traspilation.

For those who are still struggling due to the following errors:

- `Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<HTMLElement>'.`
- which leads to `Cannot use import statement outside a module` if you try to add `import` in jest.afterEnv file

Solving it with babel might lead to issues like  `Cannot use import statement outside a module` due to the fact those two work differently. So if want to solve it purely using `ts-jest` (that means in your jest config you have line similar to):

```
transform: {
  "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
},
```

and nothing from the common answers worked then follow the steps below:

1. The obvious, install `@testing-library/jest-dom` using:

```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom
```

2. Add types

```
"types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"]
```

to `tsconfig.json` similar as above.

3. In your `jest.config.js` config add the below:

```
...
setupFilesAfterEnv: [
  "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
]
...
```

4. Now, check your `roots: ["./src"],` path in your `jest.config.js`.

- Create a new file called `globals.d.ts` in that path
- Make sure it is matching the `"included"` regex within your `tsconfig.json`
- Paste into `globals.d.ts` the following line.:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
```

Don't attach this line to your *postEnv* jest setup for `ts-jest` traspiler.

Run your tests and enjoy the result.

**Side-notes:**

- My setup includes using `jest` for API testing, `jest` with `supertest` for E2E, jest with `react-testing-library` for React testing and browser `testcafe` tests with `react-testing-library` in the stack - and it all works now - so don't give up.
- Make sure in your `jest.config.js` all the extensions are covered i.e. `moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"]`, especially if you are trying to run `.tsx` tests
- If it happens that VSCode will stop highlighting in red `toBeInTheDocument()` during this process and your tests still throw the error you have likely missed the valid `types` declaration either in `tsconfig.json` or in `jest` config.

Answer (score 6):

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

These lines prepended to ***SetupTests.ts*** fixed it for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I imported `@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect`, but I was missing `@testing-library/jest-dom`. In my case, the file was named `setup-test-env.ts`, but it's whatever you specify as the `setupFilesAfterEnv` export in `jest.config.js`.

Comment: Glad it worked for you,  @ChrisCrossCrash!  :-)

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the comment, it's your eslint configuration that needs to be changed. You should update your `eslintrc` file to include a configuration override for test files:

```
  ...
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        "**/*.test.js"
      ],
      env: {
        jest: true
      }
    }
  ]
```

Where `"**/*.test.js"` is a glob that matches the format of your test files.

Changing the `eslintrc` file ensures you don't have to add the `eslint-env` comment to the top of every test file.

See this answer as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49211283/1769777
Also see the jest environment configuration: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments

Answer (score 5):

I dont know if someone need to read this. But i was stuck into this issue cuz i was re-importing some functions from jest. To avoid it, i remove this:

```
- import { describe, expect, it } from '@jest/globals';
```

Answer (score 4):

That's my solutions for this problem in my react project:

1. install `@types/testing-library__jest-dom`.

```bash
npm i -D @types/testing-library__jest-dom
```

2. according to [@testing-library/jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#with-typescript) typescript usage, we need `import '@testing-library/jest-dom'` in `jest-setup.ts` and add `setupFilesAfterEnv` to `jest.config.js`

```js
// In jest-setup.ts (or any other name)
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
```

```js
// In jest.config.js add setupFilesAfterEnv
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest-setup.js']
```

3. include `jest-setup.ts` in `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "./jest-setup.ts"
  ],
}
```

Comment: This worked for me only I installed `"@types/jest"` instead of `@types/testing-library__jest-dom`.  I also needed to make sure my `jest-setup` file was `.ts` not `.js`.  The instructions for [Usage of testing-library jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#with-typescript) really tell you all you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `pnpm` v7 or v8, Add this to your `.npmrc`:

```
public-hoist-pattern[]=*eslint*
public-hoist-pattern[]=*prettier*
public-hoist-pattern[]=@types*
```

Then, run `pnpm install`

Reference: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/4920#issuecomment-1226724790

Answer (score 2):

[Sept 2023 Answer] I'm late to the party, but using create-react-app with **pnpm**,
I managed to get rid of the problem using :

- Dev dependency `"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.3"`
- Default dependecies up-to-date :

```
"@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
```

No need to add stuff in .npmrc or create Jest config files. It just worked out of the box for me.

Comment: The only answer needed in 2024!

Answer (score 2):

In my Next.js 13 typescript project (create by `create-next-app`).

I follow Next [Testing Document](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/testing#jest-and-react-testing-library) and [example with-jest](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-jest) project to config jest test:

- have `jest`, `@testing-library/jest-dom@6.1.4`, `@testing-library/react`, `jest-environment-jsdom`, `@types/jest` installed.
- config `jest.config.js` with:

```js
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
}
```

- config `jest.setup.js` to
  `import '@testing-library/jest-dom'`

But my test file `page.test.tsx` has same error:
`"Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'Matchers<any>'."`

When I rename file extension `test.tsx` to `test.jsx` (`page.test.jsx`) it no error. So I think it's about typescript problem.

---

### Solution

In `testing-library/jest-dom` github README [With TypeScript](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#with-typescript) section
says: you need to add `"./jest-setup.ts"` (for me is `.js`) inside your `tsconfig.json` `include` config.

```json
  // In tsconfig.json
  "include": [
    ...
    "./jest-setup.js"
  ],
```

Then it fixed! I can use jest-dom expect without import `@testing-library/jest-dom` every test file.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question but I faced this problem today too.
For anyone using `Vite` and `Vitest`, together with `@testing-library/react` and `@testing-library/jest-dom`, for me this works:

```
// setup.ts
import { expect, afterEach } from 'vitest';
import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import * as matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers';

// == you should add the following import: ==
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/vitest'
// ==========================================

expect.extend(matchers);

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
});
```

This import has a reference for vite to use. After doing so, it finds the `tobeinthedocument()` in your tests

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are using different testing libraries together (e.g. Cypress and Jest). Both have `expect` with different matchers, which creates a conflict.

To fix it, you can try adding the following to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

And the following to `tsconfig.spec.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when importing types from `@jest/globals` as explained in the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#type-definitions). `testing-library/jest-dom` in `5.0.1` [moved their typed definitions in a separate package](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/123) so that it works out of the box without any config. I needed to update `testing-library/jest-dom` and `jest`, not use any extra type library, not import any types, and it works out of the box.

`setupTests.ts`

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
```

`package.json`

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.12.0"
"jest": "27.3.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using only Jest and Cypress with NextJs. The issue kept occurring after trying everything until I added cypress.config.ts file to the list of exclude in my tsconfig.json file. Inside my tsconfig file, I did:

```
{
    "exclude": [..., "./cypress.config.ts"],
    ...
}
```

You can check this link for more info: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22059

Answer (score 1):

Besides all the answers mentioned in the comments above in my case replacing *'import'* with *'require'* helped. Even though all other inner files are imported via 'import' and other settings from the comments above were implemented too, they didn't help until I've changed the import

```
const { expect, describe, it } = require('@jest/globals');
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Feburary 2024]**

Install @types/jest and @testing-library/jest-dom as a dev dependencies.

In tsconfig set;

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["jest", "jest-dom"]
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "node_modules/@testing-library"]
  }
}
```

*@testing-library/jest-dom* contains the types we need. The 'typeroot' entry is required because by default the 'type' property only looks in the @types folder within node_modules, so we have to point it to the @testing-library package too.

Then the 'type' field narrows down which types we actually want to utilize (from @types by default, but in this case from both paths in typeroots).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you add: 
`import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"` 
after: 
`import { render } from "@testing-library/react"`

```
import React from "react"
import { render } from "@testing-library/react"
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
```

Comment: Can you explain how/why this would fix it? If you're importing `@testing-library/jest-dom` already then the rest of it is already imported

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error while integrating `Enzyme` with `Jest`, make sure you use `jest` assertion methods.

In `Enzyme` documentation examples `chai` assertions are used. Instead of that we have to use `jest` assertions.

Ex. Use

```
expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).toHaveLength(3);
```

instead of

```
expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.lengthOf(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I messed with this for a couple of hours and read all the Q&A sites. Nothing worked, except for moving `@testing-library/react` and `@testing-library/jest-dom` out of `devDependencies`, and into `dependencies`.

I don't know why they're needed for production exactly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using Cypress and Testing Library, it's notable to say that I'm also using Cypress testing library, which makes necessary to create a `tsconfig.json` inside Cypress folder. Down bellow I'll let the libraries related to testing I'm using and the fix I've done.

```
// package.json
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^10.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
    "cypress": "^13.3.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.4",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.4",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
```

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "./.jest/setup.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "cypress", "cypress.config.ts"]
}
```

```
// ./cypress/ts.config.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress", "node"]
  },
  "include": ["../cypress.config.ts", "**/*.ts"]
}
```

Which fix it was added cypress at this line in the root `tsconfig.json`:

`"exclude": ["node_modules", "cypress", "cypress.config.ts"]`

Hope it fix the error for you too, peace!

Answer (score 0):

I spent a day and use tons of tutorials and documentation to handle this issue but it didn't work out. And only two steps helped me.

1. I just removed imports `@jest/globals` from test files.
2. I was trying to get rid of this issue during some package installation I noticed that I got changes in `"scripts"` field in `package.json`, and I reverted it from `"test": "jest"` to `"test": "react-scripts test"` and It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing everything right as suggested by above answers but was doing a silly mistake of not not including the file with the line `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';` in `tsconfig.json`

My tsconfig configuration was

```
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
```

So I changed it to

```
  "include": ["src/**/*", "./jest.setup.js"],
```

in tsconfig.json