# Vite / Jest / React-Testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am trying to test in React application with Jest; my application uses Vite as a module bundler. The issue is, every time I run tests I get the following error:

```
   > react-test@0.0.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  src/test/App.test.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to 
enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript      
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    SyntaxError: C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\react-test\src\test\App.test.jsx: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (8:30):

       6 |
       7 | test("renders content", ()=>{
    >  8 |     const component = render(<App></App>)
         |                              ^
       9 |     console.log(component)
      10 | })

    Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
    If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.

      at Parser._raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:150:45)
      at Parser.raiseWithData (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:145:17)
      at Parser.expectOnePlugin (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:214:18)
      at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1238:16)
      at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:682:23)
      at Parser.parseUpdate (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:662:21)
      at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:633:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:388:14)        
      at Parser.parseExprOps (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:398:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:356:23)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.379 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg|png)$": "<rootDir>/test/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.16.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.0.7",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "vite": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

App.test.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "../App.jsx";


test("renders content", ()=>{
    const component = render(<App></App>)
    console.log(component)
})
```

Answer (score 9):

The error output is correct, Jest runs on your local node binary and requires that your jsx files be transformed into a syntax it can understand.

Vite does not so this transformation by default. It was designed to transpile and bundle your code into some `bundle.js` that is appropriate for the browser (it *can* do other types of output, like libraries. You'd need to tweak your `vite.config.js`).

Luckily, other folks have solved this problem for you. I'd recommend using [vitest](https://vitest.dev/), since you wouldn't need to download another transformer or invest a lot of time into setting up tricky build scripts.

Here's a guide on how to quickly set it up:

https://www.eternaldev.com/blog/testing-a-react-application-with-vitest/

And a migration guide:

https://vitest.dev/guide/migration.html

Answer (score 0):

*This is for beginner to setup from scratch with: Vite, Jest, React, Typescript*

- *I heard Vite & Jest are not compatible, to some extend. 

  But for me, at current stage, it seems working.*
- *(Though, I dont have in-depth knowledge on this, not sure did I miss anything.)*
- *(if you use `npm` instead of `pnpm`, just replace `pnpm add` with `npm install`, it should work)*

#### procedure

1. 

setup Vite 
choose React Typescript 
install Jest & React Testing Library

```bash
pnpm create vite
pnpm add --save-dev jest @types/jest ts-jest @testing-library/jest-dom @testing-library/react @testing-library/user-event
```

1. 

create the main test file `Greet.test.tsx` under `proj-test-vitejest/src`, 
make sure you `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';`

```
// import { describe, expect, test, it } from '@jest/globals'; // this doesnt work...
// import { describe, expect, test, it } from '@testing-library/jest-dom';
// import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
// import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
// import 'jest-dom/extend-expect';
// import { Greet } from './Greet';

import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Greet', () => {
  test('find AA', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<div>Banana and Apple</div>);
    const textElement = getByText(/Banana/); // screen.getByText(/Banana/);
    expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('find BB', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<div>Banana and Apple</div>);
    const textElement = getByText(/Mango/);
    expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

now the typescript eslint, intellisense, import, should be all good 
there is no need to manually change `tsconfig.json` or `package.json` at this point

- you should not encounter issues like [Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'Matchers<any>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861187/property-tobeinthedocument-does-not-exist-on-type-matchersany) \

  you should be able to find the method `toBeInTheDocument()` in 
  `H:\Using\proj-test-vitejest\node_modules\.pnpm\@testing-library+jest-dom@6.1.4_@types+jest@29.5.10_jest@29.7.0\node_modules\@testing-library\jest-dom\types\matchers.d.ts`

  other procedures like following are not required at this point

  - `"types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],`
  - `setupFilesAfterEnv: [ "<rootDir>/support/setupTests.js" ],`
  - `npm install @types/testing-library__jest-dom -D`

1. 

run `npx jest`, you will fail

```bash
SyntaxError: H:\Using\proj-test-vitejest\src\Greet.test.tsx: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (13:12):
```

so 
create `jest.config.ts` 
add following to `jest.config.ts`

```
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$': 'ts-jest',
    },
```

> [Babel throwing Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820035/babel-throwing-support-for-the-experimental-syntax-jsx-isnt-currently-enabled)

1. 

`npx jest` try again, you fail with

```bash
Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file H:\Using\proj-test-vitejest\jest.config.ts
  Error: Jest: 'ts-node' is required for the TypeScript configuration files. Make sure it is installed
```

so

```
pnpm install --save-dev ts-node
```

1. 

`npx jest` try again, you fail with

````bash
    The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
    Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.```
````

```bash
  Test environment jest-environment-jsdom cannot be found. Make sure the testEnvironment configuration option points to an existing node module.
```

so 
add following to `jest.config.ts`

```
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
```

```
pnpm add --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom
```

1. 

`npx jest` try again, you **success** now. 
the results are (1 success, 1 fail (intentionally))

#### others

1. 

if you are tired of `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';` in every test file

you can comment it out in `Greet.test.tsx`

```
// import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

create `jest.setup.ts` under `proj-test-vitejest/src`,

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
// import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

add following to `jest.config.ts`

```
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
      // '@testing-library/jest-dom',
      // "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect",
      '<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'
    ],
```

create `Globals.d.ts` under `proj-test-vitejest/src`,

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
// import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
// declare module '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

add following to `tsconfig.json`

```json
  "include": ["src", "Globals.d.ts"],
```

> [Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'Matchers<any>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861187/property-tobeinthedocument-does-not-exist-on-type-matchersany)

#### overview

- terminal log

  ```bash
  PS H:\Using> pnpm create vite
  ../.pnpm-store/v3/tmp/dlx-5716           |   +1 +
  ../.pnpm-store/v3/tmp/dlx-5716           | Progress: resolved 1, reused 1, downloaded 0, added 1, done
  √ Project name: ... proj-test-vitejest
  √ Select a framework: » React
  √ Select a variant: » TypeScript

  Scaffolding project in H:\Using\proj-test-vitejest...

  Done. Now run:

    cd proj-test-vitejest
    pnpm install
    pnpm run dev

  PS H:\Using> cd proj-test-vitejest
  PS H:\Using\proj-test-vitejest> pnpm add --save-dev jest @types/jest ts-jest @testing-library/jest-dom @testing-library/react @testing-library/user-event
  Packages: +456
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  Progress: resolved 489, reused 456, downloaded 0, added 456, done

  dependencies:
  + react 18.2.0
  + react-dom 18.2.0

  devDependencies:
  + @testing-library/jest-dom 6.1.4
  + @testing-library/react 14.1.2
  + @testing-library/user-event 14.5.1
  + @types/jest 29.5.10
  + @types/react 18.2.39
  + @types/react-dom 18.2.17
  + @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin 6.13.1
  + @typescript-eslint/parser 6.13.1
  + @vitejs/plugin-react 4.2.0
  + eslint 8.54.0
  + eslint-plugin-react-hooks 4.6.0
  + eslint-plugin-react-refresh 0.4.4
  + jest 29.7.0
  + ts-jest 29.1.1
  + typescript 5.3.2
  + vite 5.0.3

  Done in 1m 15.7s
  PS H:\Using\proj-test-vitejest> code .
  PS H:\Using\proj-test-vitejest> pnpm install --save-dev ts-node
  Packages: +19 -6
  +++++++++++++++++++------
  Progress: resolved 502, reused 469, downloaded 0, added 19, done

  devDependencies:
  + ts-node 10.9.1

  Done in 2.6s
  PS H:\Using\proj-test-vitejest> pnpm add --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom
   WARN  2 deprecated subdependencies found: abab@2.0.6, domexception@4.0.0
  Packages: +47
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  Progress: resolved 549, reused 516, downloaded 0, added 47, done

  devDependencies:
  + jest-environment-jsdom 29.7.0

  Done in 3.5s
  PS H:\Using\proj-test-vitejest> npx jest
  ts-jest[config] (WARN) message TS151001: If you have issues related to imports, you should consider setting `esModuleInterop` to `true` in your TypeScript configuration file (usually `tsconfig.json`). See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/01/31/announcing-typescript-2-7/#easier-ecmascript-module-interoperability for more information.
  FAIL  src/Greet.test.tsx
    Greet
      √ find AA (24 ms)
      × find BB (6 ms)

    ● Greet › find BB

      TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /Mango/. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

      Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
      <body>
        <div>
          <div>
            Banana and Apple
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>

        18 |   test('find BB', () => {
        19 |     const { getByText } = render(<div>Banana and Apple</div>);
      > 20 |     const textElement = getByText(/Mango/);
          |                         ^
        21 |     expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();
        22 |   });
        23 | });

        at Object.getElementError (node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+dom@9.3.3/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:37:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (src/Greet.test.tsx:20:25)

  Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
  Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
  Snapshots:   0 total
  Time:        2.481 s
  Ran all test suites.
  PS H:\Using\proj-test-vitejest>
  ```
- `package.json`

  ```json
  {
    "name": "proj-test-vitejest",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
      "dev": "vite",
      "build": "tsc && vite build",
      "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
      "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "react": "^18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
      "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
      "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
      "@types/jest": "^29.5.10",
      "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
      "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.10.0",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
      "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
      "eslint": "^8.53.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
      "jest": "^29.7.0",
      "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
      "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
      "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
      "typescript": "^5.2.2",
      "vite": "^5.0.0"
    }
  }
  ```
- `jest.config.ts`

  ```
  import type { Config } from 'jest';

  export default async (): Promise<Config> => {
    return {
      // verbose: true,
      // roots: ['<rootDir>/src'], // , '<rootDir>/test'],
      // testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)'],
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
      transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$': 'ts-jest',
      },
      setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        // '@testing-library/jest-dom',
        // "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect",
        '<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'
      ],
    };
  };
  ```
- `tsconfig.json`

  ```json
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2020",
      "useDefineForClassFields": true,
      "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
      "module": "ESNext",
      "skipLibCheck": true,

      /* Bundler mode */
      "moduleResolution": "bundler",
      "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "jsx": "react-jsx",

      /* Linting */
      "strict": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
    },
    "include": ["src", "Globals.d.ts"],
    "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
  }
  ```
- folder structure & image

  [image: folder structure & image]