# TypeScript error 'Cannot find name 'expect'' when creating React app with Create React App and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg

```bash
TS2339: Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<HTMLElement>'.
     6 |   render(<App />);
     7 |   const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  >  8 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
       |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     9 | });
```

Whenever I create a react app using

```bash
yarn create react-app <app-name> --template typescript
```

I get these Errors and they can be removed by deleting `App.test.tsx` file but I want a permanent fix.

```bash
TS2339: Property 'toBeInTheDocument' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<HTMLElement>'.
     6 |   render(<App />);
     7 |   const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  >  8 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
       |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     9 | });
```

Comment: do you have jest installed?

Comment: Thier is post on stackoverflow that has the fix for this problem [FIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547215/react-testing-library-why-is-tobeinthedocument-not-a-function#56557915)